# Yii2 data-method post not working in gridView

Tags: gridview, yii2

In a cell of a dataColumn in gridView i've placed a link with data-method = post, and a data-confirm = 'Some confirm vessage'. But when you click the link it works with get method, and no confirm message is displayed. Why it does not work?
Here is the code:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $model->orders
        ]),
        'columns' => [
            //... some other columns .... Then:
            [
                'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'bg-teal color-palette'],
                'footerOptions' => ['class' => 'bg-teal color-palette'],
                'format' => 'html',
                'value' => function($model)
                {
                    return Html::a(
                        'Delete',
                        [
                            'order/delete',
                            'id' => $model->id
                        ],
                        [
                            'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
                            'data-confirm' => 'Do you realy want to delete the item?',
                            'data-method' => 'post',
                        ]
                    );
                }
            ],
    ]); ?>
```

If i place the Html::a outside the gridView it works fine. Am i doing somthing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 'format' property of data cell needs to be 'raw' in this case, as 'html' filters out a lot of stuff.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $model->orders
    ]),
    'columns' => [
        //... some other columns .... Then:
        [
            'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'bg-teal color-palette'],
            'footerOptions' => ['class' => 'bg-teal color-palette'],
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return Html::a(
                    'Delete',
                    [
                        'order/delete',
                        'id' => $model->id
                    ],
                    [
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
                        'data-confirm' => 'Do you realy want to delete the item?',
                        'data-method' => 'post',
                    ]
                );
            }
        ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Milos Ozegovic, this worked. Maybe someone knows about other data-  atributes used i yii2, or where to find information.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation for those attributes, but I only found that some of them are handled in yii.js file https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.js

There are a couple of attributes I know, data-method, data-confirm, and data-params-* with which you can define params to be sent via data-method. Hope you understand me :)

Comment: To @Milos Ozegovic. Here is a list of other data-* attributes. Thanks to Bizley.